# Получить из одного IEnumerable три за один обход

Tags: c#, linq

В некотором отчёте нужно отобразить три "кучки" покупателей (условно назовём их "золотыми", "серебряными" и "бронзовыми"):

- кто сделал покупки на сумму свыше 100 000 рублей,
- свыше 50 000 рублей (но не добрал до 100 тыс.),
- свыше 10 тыс рублей (и не набрал 50 тыс.).

У меня есть некоторый IEnumerable, где в CustomerDto лежат Id клиента и его имя, а также есть поле хранящее сумму покупок - Amount.

В принципе, я могу три раза вырезать нужные мне данные через Where:

```
var report = new CustomersDto
{
    Gold   = allCustomers.Where(x => x.Amount > 100000),
    Silver = allCustomers.Where(x => x.Amount >  50000 && x.Amount < 100000),
    Bronze = allCustomers.Where(x => x.Amount >  10000 && x.Amount <  50000),
};
```

Но мне стало любопытно: а можно ли сразу за один обход allCustomers получить нужные мне данные?

Т.е. что-то вроде:

```
CustomersDto report = allCustomers.Something(
    x => x.Amount > 100000,
    x => x.Amount >  50000 && x.Amount < 100000,
    x => x.Amount >  10000 && x.Amount <  50000);
```

Такое возможно?

Comment: Прикол в том, что `GroupBy` сам по себе (текущая реализация) [материализует запрос в `Lookup`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,2531), это значит, что можно написать `var grouped = allCustomers.GroupBy(c => GetCustomerStatus(c));` и потом обращение к `grouped` не будет перечитывать `allCustomers`, конечно, с `IQueryable` это может не прокатить, но можно для верности (да и для удобства) добавить к `GroupBy` еще `.ToDictionary(g => g.Key)` и за один проход получить словарь с группами покупателей, потом просто пишем `Gold = grouped[Statuses.Gold]` и т.д

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используя только IEnumerable такого трюка сделать не получится. Но этого можно достичь используя IObservable и Rx.NET (оно же System.Reactive).

Сначала нужно превратить allCustomers в IObservable:

```
var source = allCustomers.ToObservable().Publish();
```

Метод Publish используется для того, чтобы избежать многократного обхода исходной последовательности.

Теперь, если свойства класса CustomersDto имеют подходящий тип, можно поступить вот так:

```
var report = new CustomersDto
{
    Gold   = source.Where(x => x.Amount > 100000).ToListObservable(),
    Silver = source.Where(x => x.Amount >  50000 && x.Amount < 100000).ToListObservable(),
    Bronze = source.Where(x => x.Amount >  10000 && x.Amount <  50000).ToListObservable(),
};
source.Connect();
```

Если же их тип - конкретный класс вроде `List<Customer>`, придется сделать чуть сложнее:

```
var report = new CustomersDto
{
    Gold   = new List<Customer>(),
    Silver = new List<Customer>(),
    Bronze = new List<Customer>()
};
source.Where(x => x.Amount > 100000).Subscribe(report.Gold.Add);
source.Where(x => x.Amount >  50000 && x.Amount < 100000).Subscribe(report.Silver.Add);
source.Where(x => x.Amount >  10000 && x.Amount <  50000).Subscribe(report.Bronze.Add);
source.Connect();
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно исхитриться и все же получить из одного `IEnumerable<Customer>` три таковых)

Моя идея состоит в том, чтобы использовать стандартный `GroupBy`. Приступим:

0) Опишем структуру покупателя, которую будем использовать:

```
public class Customer
{
    public ulong ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public double Amount { get; private set; }

    public Customer(ulong ID, string Name, double Amount)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Amount = Amount;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{ID}: {Name} - {Amount}руб.";
}
```

1) Опишу вспомогательный `enum`:

```
public enum CustomerType
{
    // < 10k
    None,

    // >= 10k && < 50k 
    Bronze,

    // >= 50k && < 100k
    Silver,

    // >= 100k
    Gold
}
```

2) Напишем `метод-расширение` (я исхожу из того, что Вы не можете по каким-то причинам менять изначального класса. В противном случае Вы можете прямо в нем создать аналогичное свойство)):

```
public static class CustomerHelper
{
    // Получим тип покупателя, исходя из его счета:
    public static CustomerType GetCustomerType(this Customer Customer) => (CustomerType)(Customer.Amount < 10000 ? 0 : Customer.Amount < 50000 ? 1 : Customer.Amount < 100000 ? 2 : 3);
}
```

3) Опишем структуру класса `CustomersDto`:

```
public class CustomersDto
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Bronze { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Silver { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Gold { get; set; }

    public CustomersDto()
    {
        Bronze = new Customer[0];
        Silver = new Customer[0];
        Gold = new Customer[0];
    }

    public CustomersDto(IEnumerable<Customer> Customers) : this()
    {
        // Сгруппируем покупателей по типу и избавимся от тех, кто недобрал 10к
        var grouped = Customers.GroupBy(x => x.GetCustomerType()).Where(x => x.Key != CustomerType.None);

        // Установим нужные поля
        foreach (var group in grouped)
            SetCustomers(group.Key, group.Select(x => x));
    }

    public void SetCustomers(CustomerType Type, IEnumerable<Customer> Customers)
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case CustomerType.Bronze:
                Bronze = Customers;
                break;
            case CustomerType.Silver:
                Silver = Customers;
                break;
            case CustomerType.Gold:
                Gold = Customers;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

4) Протестируем:

```
// Тестовые покупатели
Customer[] allCustomers = new[] {
    new Customer(0, "Vasya", 5000),
    new Customer(1, "Petya", 11000),
    new Customer(2, "Vanya", 14500),
    new Customer(3, "Stepan", 50000),
    new Customer(4, "Kir", 57000),
    new Customer(5, "AK", 100000)
};

// Инициализируем наш класс
CustomersDto dto = new CustomersDto(allCustomers);

// Выведем результат:
Console.WriteLine("Bronze:");
foreach (Customer bronze in dto.Bronze)
    Console.WriteLine(bronze);

Console.WriteLine("\nSilver:");
foreach (Customer silver in dto.Silver)
    Console.WriteLine(silver);

Console.WriteLine("\nGold:");
foreach (Customer gold in dto.Gold)
    Console.WriteLine(gold);
```

И получим такой вот вывод:

> Bronze: 
>   1: Petya - 11000руб.
> 2: Vanya - 14500руб.
>
> Silver:
> 3: Stepan - 50000руб.
> 4: Kir - 57000руб.
>
> Gold:
> 5: AK - 100000руб.

Собственно, все как надо)

---

К слову, сначала я хотел сделать так:

```
// Сгруппируем -> Уберем тех, у кого меньше 10к -> Отсортируем по ключу -> Оставим лишь IEnumerable<IEnumarable<Customer>>
var grouped = Customers.GroupBy(x => x.GetCustomerType()).Where(x => x.Key != CustomerType.None).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Select(y => y));

Bronze = grouped.ElementAt(0);
Silver = grouped.ElementAt(1);
Gold = grouped.ElementAt(2);
```

Тогда в `grouped` действительно будет лежать **3** `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Customer>>` *при текущем наборе данных*

Но потом я вспомнил, что какой-то из групп может и вовсе не быть, так что доступ по индексу - плохая идея)

Можно, конечно, извратиться с `Union` и пустыми `IGrouping`, но это уже какой-то мазохизм...)
Если Вам будет интересно - допишу и этот вариант. Тогда решение будет полностью соответствовать задаче: получить **3** коллекции из одной)

Comment: А я вот не подумал, что некоторых групп не обнаружится :( но подобный вариант с IGrouping у меня мелькал в голове.

Comment: @AK, ну если проект огромный, то их и правда скорее всего не обнаружится (точнее, вероятность того, что ни одного человека не окажется в какой-то из трёх групп стремится к невозможной). Но у нас ведь нельзя не рассматривать и таких вариантов...)

Answer (score 3):

Вот также через группировку.

```
var groups = new List<(Func<int,bool>,int)>
{
    ( a =>  a > 100000, 0),
    ( a =>  50000 <  a && a < 100000, 1),
    ( a =>  a < 50000, 2)
};

var split = customers.GroupBy(c => groups.First(g => g.Item1(c.Amount)).Item2)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Далее можно достать по индексу или превратить в словарь. 
ИМХО. Все это все равно немного муторнее, чем шлепнуть 3 раза `Where`

Comment: Согласен, что в прикладной задаче проще шлёпнуть три Where, но вопрос был интересен как исследовательская задача, вдруг бы попались любопытные варианты на будущее чтобы "вдруг пригодится иметь под рукой".

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать `Aggregate`:

```
var report = allCustomers.Aggregate<Customer, CustomersDto>(new CustomersDto
{
    Gold = new List<Customer>(),
    Silver = new List<Customer>(),
    Bronze = new List<Customer>()
},
(dto, cust) =>
{
    if (cust.Amount > 100000)
        dto.Gold.Add(cust);
    else if (cust.Amount > 50000)
        dto.Silver.Add(cust);
    else if (cust.Amount > 10000)
        dto.Bronze.Add(cust);
    return dto;
});
```

При условии, что

```
class CustomersDto
{
    public List<Customer> Gold { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Silver { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Bronze { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Этот вариант был пожалуй первым, что мне пришло в голову - сделать `.ForEach()` и вынести if в отдельную функцию. Галку я всё же оставлю на варианте IObservable (не могу оценить, насколько там большие накладные расходы), но ваш вариант пожалуй наиболее простой из остальных.

Comment: Если все равно все свелось в серии if - то проще уж цикл foreach написать. Что тут упрощает Aggregate?

Comment: @PavelMayorov - лично я бы сделал с `foreach` (я и хотел приписку про это сделать). Но всё-таки `Aggregate` - это своего рода linq-way, а вопрос именно про это, имхо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov неа, linq-way - это фильтрация через Where